# Is there a way to keep windows 7 thumbnail preview open for a particular app?

Tags: windows-7, gui, aero

Alternatively, a gadget or other utility to serve a similar function would be welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried few of the software for doing this. Now, I got a good one [on top replica](http://ontopreplica.codeplex.com).

> A real-time, always on top, "replica" of a window of your choice, based on DWM Thumbnails.
>   Completely written in C# for .NET 4.0/4.5, makes use of the Windows Forms Aero library

Note: You need to have a .net 4.0 framework installed for this to work properly.

Comment: If you link to a product, please provide the name of the product and a description of how it works so if the link breaks it could still be found with a search.

Comment: I keep forgetting what this software is called, and when searching for `windows thumbnail preview` or `live preview thumbnail` nothing shows up. Eventually found it with: `live thumbnail previews windows 7 -off -disable -enable`. The app has an orange icon